# Use Image filters for WMS Layers in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, wms, display

In QGIS, I can use image filters / color rendering to adjust the display of WMS Layers (see image below). This is very useful, since WMS Layers are images and there symbology cannot be changed.

In ArcMap I found the option to remove a background color, but other than that, I don't see any options to change how the layer is displayed. **Is it possible to do something like "Multiply-Rendering" with WMS Layers in ArcMap?**

[image: Color Rendering in QGIS]

Comment: WMS symbology can be changed using SLD passed through a GetMap request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcMap does not support blending modes. This is a feature found in ArcGIS Pro starting with version 2.7.

ArcGIS Pro Release Notes: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm#GUID-2F3B2C01-76F7-4AE5-B897-5E859EACBA4D